# Pass param with @using (Html.BeginForm FormMethod.Get

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("testGrid", "Transport", new { id= 3062 }, FormMethod.Get))
{
```

How I can pass the param(id) with [HttpGet] in asp.net mvc without use submit

Comment: Do you need to pass only id or some more params?

Comment: Thank you for replay, I need paraam for example "Id, type " and more